# Workflow to send email

Tags: list, outgoing-email

I wanted to create a list in share point in which people add their details & attach file. However, not able to edit the same, only owner/specific group has the access for the same and get email of the same.

I've achieved the same by changing permission level and creating new permission level "Restricted Contribute" with add permission. But then, when a user (with "Restricted contribute" permission) creating an item, sharepoint is not applying workflow to the specific item. But owner and contribute access people are able to do it without any problem.

Would anyone please help me in create a workflow and list which generate email to specific people and if user add information and owner change information in the list and restricted access

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SharePoint?

If 2010 or later, you can add an Impersonation Step to a 2010 style workflow that will use the workflow creator's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using App step action in sharepoint designer workflow.

Follow the steps given [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo.md) to setup the app step permissions on your site.

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: Nope. scope changed now